# Why are my Keyboard LEDs blinking when shut down?

Tags: windows-8, keyboard, led

Recently my keyboard LEDs started blinking when my PC is shut down (see video [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6hlbhpt9l82qdu1/Keyboard%20blinking.MOV?dl=1), sorry for the quality). Only when the PC is shut down, as soon as I boot they stop blinking.
I think it started after I disabled hibernation in Windows, but can't say for sure.
It doesn't seem to cause amy harm (so far), but I'm curious, has anyone else seen this and knows what it could be?

System specs:
Intel DP43BF, Intel Q9550, NVidia GForce 210, Win 8.1

Comment: Since you disabled hibernation, perhaps it is now suspended iso. really shut down?

Comment: > really shut down? How could I check?

Comment: Eg. from the commandline: "shutdown.exe -s -t 00".  Now, do the leds still blink?

Comment: Ah that's interesting! Nope, they don't blink when I do this. What does it mean? Maybe an USB device (I have a few connected, e.g. an USB soundcard) preventing complete shutdown? (I can at least now use that command instead of Win GUI for shutting down to prevent it so thanks already.)

Comment: I'll add an answer in that sense.  It may be normal for Windows 8 not to shutdown completely.  Makes you think it's booting much faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[HowtoGeek](https://www.howtogeek.com/77061/how-to-add-shutdown-restart-sleep-to-the-windows-8-metro-start-screen/) shows you how you can add tiles to your desktop to really shut down, or put your system simply to sleep.  The commandline solution is:

```
shutdown.exe -s -t 00
```

but putting it to sleep is more complex.

Until now you probably always "hibernated" your system, in stead of really shutting down.  It makes booting a lot faster.

[Online Tech Tips](https://www.online-tech-tips.com/windows-8/perform-a-complete-shutdown-in-windows-8/) seem to have come to the same conclusion.  A real shutdown is a bit of a hassle.

Comment: According to the page you linked I did a "powercfg /hibernate off" in commandline and that seems to have fixed the blinking also when shutting down via Win GUI. (I upvoted your answer but it's not publicly visible due to my low reputation. Thanks.)

Comment: Well, I would appreciate it if you simply accepted my answer ;-)

Comment: Duh I totally missed that, wasn't on StackExchange for a long time, sorry. Done now. :)